# Where Are the Default EditText Images Located?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I can't find the default nine patch images for the EditText widget.

I am looking in android-sdk\platforms\android-8\data\res\drawable and see mostly a gang of xml files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are in the density-specific drawable directories (drawable-mdpi, etc).

Answer (score 4):

They are located in `android-sdk\platforms\android-8\data\res\drawable-hdpi` and `drawable-mdpi` respectively based on resolution.

They are called

```
editbox_background_focus_yellow.9.png
editbox_background_normal.9.png
editbox_dropdown_background.9.png
editbox_dropdown_background_dark.9.png
```